# Why is my swift initializers not appearing?

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying to call my `func`. Here is the code:

```
class fnitekCo {
    var name = ""
    var contact = ""
    var location = ""
    var about = ""
    init(_ name:String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    func disPlay() {
        print("\(name)" )
        print("\(contact)")
        print ("\(location)")
        print ("\(about)")
    }
}
```

---

```
class Employee: fnitekCo {
    var owner = ""
    var manager = ""
    var salesRep = ""
    var branchRep = ""
    var role = ""
    override init (_ name: String) {
        super.init(name)
        self.role = "tecnician"
    }
    func disPlay2() {
        print("We have the finest representatives to work with you and find you the best solutions to for your IT services")      
        print("Owner: I'm \(owner), I think this world will be a better future technology")
        print("Im the manager and my name is \(manager), i oversea the branches")
        print("Im \(salesRep), and i recommend the best solutions for you")  
        print("We have a lot of branches located in \(location), \(branchRep) controls that aspect")
    }
}
```

---

```
class Solutions: Employee {
    var services = ""   
    func disPlay3() {
        print("We provide a range of services from Wifi routers, ethernet cables, gaming solutions, pc solutions based off your needs. This is the plan called \(services)")
    }
}
```

---

```
let f = fnitekCo()
f.name = "Fnitek"
f.about = "We find solutions to your needs"
f.contact = "airviewshots@gmail.com"
f.location = "Los angeles"
f.disPlay()
let e = Employee()
e.owner = "Cheebi Mere"
e.manager = "Chigo"
e.salesRep = "Santos"
e.branchRep =  "Chike"
e.disPlay2()
let s = Solutions()
s.services = "Fn1"
s.disPlay3()
//I'm trying to call these init function below
let meOwner = fnitekCo("tim")
print(meOwner.name)
let Employ = Employee("joe")
print (Employ.name)
print(Employ.role)
```

Comment: What's a `FnitekCo`, and why does `Employee` inherit from it? Why the heck is a `Solutions` (why is it plural?) an `Employee`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] for tips how to improve your question. Make sure to explain what exactly is not working.

Comment: finitekCo is my comapny i'm starting, and i just used this as a example on how ill right code for my website.

Answer (score 5):

There is no initializer called `Employee()` (a.k.a. `Employee.init()`). You only provided
`Employee.init(_:)`. It requires an argument to the `String` parameter called `name` (but with no label, hence the `_`)

More problematically, you're trying to make "empty" instances (what the hell does it mean to have an employee whose owner is `""`, whose manager is `""`, role is `""`, and so on? It's complete non-sense, yet it's possible with this model), and later assigned values. This is very error prone. You should make initializers that set all fields, which guarantee strong invariants of your objects, and remove the empty strings.

Something roughly like this:

```
class FnitekCo { // What the heck is a FnitekCo???
    let name: String
    let contact: String?
    let location: String?
    let about: String?
    
    init(
        name: String,
        contact: String?,
        location: String?,
        about: String?
    ) {
        self.name = name
        self.contact = contact
        self.location = location
        self.about = about
    }
    
    func display() {
        print("\(name)" )
        // FIXME: Handle these optionals.
//      print("\(contact)")
//      print("\(location)")
//      print("\(about)")
    }
}

class Employee: FnitekCo {
    let owner: String // FIXME: An employee has an owner? That sounds like slavery to me...
    let manager: String
    let salesRep: String
    let branchRep: String
    let role: String
    
    init (
        name: String,
        contact: String?,
        location: String?,
        about: String?,
        owner: String,
        manager: String,
        salesRep: String,
        branchRep: String,
        role: String
    ) {
        self.owner = owner
        self.manager = manager
        self.salesRep = salesRep
        self.branchRep = branchRep
        self.role = role
        
        super.init(
            name: name,
            contact: contact,
            location: location,
            about: about
        )
    }
    
    func display2() {
        
        print ( "We have the finest representatives to work with you and find you the best solutions to for your IT services")
        
        print ("Owner: I'm \(owner), I think this world will be a better future technology")
        print("Im the manager and my name is \(manager), i oversea the branches")
        
        print("Im \(salesRep), and i recommend the best solutions for you")
        
        // FIXME: Handle these optionals.
//      print("We have a lot of branches located in \(location), \(branchRep) controls that aspect")
    }
    
}


class Solutions {
    let services: String
    
    init(services: String) {
        self.services = services
    }
    
    func display3() {
        print("We provide a range of services from Wifi routers, ethernet cables, gaming solutions, pc solutions based off your needs. This is the plan called \(services)")
    }
}




let f = FnitekCo(
    name: "Fnitek",
    contact: "airviewshots@gmail.com",
    location: "Los angeles",
    about: "We find solutions to your needs."
)

f.display()

let e = Employee(
    name: "I need a name", // FIXME
    contact: nil,
    location: nil,
    about: nil,
    owner: "Cheebi Mere",
    manager: "Chigo",
    salesRep: "Santos",
    branchRep: "Chike",
    role: "I need a role" // FIXME
)

e.display2()


let s = Solutions(services: "Fn1")

s.display3()


let meOwner = FnitekCo(
    name: "tim",
    contact: nil,
    location: nil,
    about: nil
)
print(meOwner.name)


let employee = Employee(
    name: "joe",
    contact: nil,
    location: nil,
    about: nil,
    owner: "GIVE ME A VALUE", // FIXME
    manager: "GIVE ME A VALUE", // FIXME
    salesRep: "GIVE ME A VALUE",
    branchRep: "GIVE ME A VALUE",
    role: "tecnician"
)

print(employee.name)
print(employee.role)
```